# Mount volume from host in Dockerfile long format

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, bind, volumes

When configuring a `docker-compose.yml`, I can easily mount a volume that maps a folder from the host machine to the container:

```
...
    volumes:
      - "/host/folder/:/container/folder/"
...
```

However, if I try to use the *long syntax*, that doesn't work anymore:

```
...
volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: /host/folder
        target: /container/folder/
...
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-3)

> source: the source of the mount, a path on the host for a bind mount,
> or the **name of a volume defined in the top-level volumes key**. Not
> applicable for a tmpfs mount.

So, it seems that in the long syntax I have to use the bind type to mount a host path. Does this make sense, different features according to syntax?

Furthermore, again, according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/),

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by
> and used by Docker containers. While bind mounts are dependent on the
> directory structure and OS of the host machine, volumes are completely
> managed by Docker.

So, I much prefer having volumes instead of binds. Do I have to use the *short syntax* for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type:` field says whether it's a named `volume`, a `bind` mount, or a couple of other things.  Since you're mounting a host directory, you need to specify `type: bind` in the extended syntax.

```yaml
volumes:
  - type: bind         # <-- not "volume"
    source: /host/folder
    target: /container/folder/
```

> according to the docs, "volumes are [...] preferred...."

IMHO the Docker documentation is very enthusiastic about named volumes and glosses over their downsides.  Since you can't access the contents of a named volume from outside of Docker, they're harder to back up and manage, and a poor match for tasks like injecting config files and reviewing logs.  I would not automatically reach for a named volume because the Docker documentation suggests it's preferred.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  some-application:
    volumes:

      # Use a bind mount to inject configuration files; you need to
      # directly edit them on the host
      - type: bind
        source: ./config
        target: /app/config

      # Use a bind mount to read back log files; you need to read them
      # on the host
      - type: bind
        source: ./log
        target: /app/data

      # Use a named volume for opaque application data; you do not
      # need to manipulate files on the host, and on MacOS/Windows
      # a named volume will be faster
      - type: volume
        source: app-data  # when type: volume, this is a volume name
        target: /app/data

      # Do not mount anything over /app or the code in the image.

volumes:
  app-data:
```

Comment: When I use the short syntax, is it really using bind behind the curtains?

Comment: Yes; `volumes: [/host/path:/container/path]` is bind-mount syntax and `volumes: [volume-name:/container/path]` (without any slashes in the `volume-name`) is a named volume mount.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
...
services:
  some-service:
    image: some-image
    volumes:
      - my-volume-name:/some-path-in-container
volumes:
  my-volume-name:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/my-host-folder'
...
```

Comment: The long syntax allows to specify the type directly as "bind", my point was to use a volume type instead of bind. Thanks.

Comment: How this differ from `type: bind` syntax at other answer?