# How to expose vite js host to the outside docker

Tags: laravel, docker, vite

I'm new in vite js when upgrade from Laravel version 8 to 9.
I'm building docker for a Laravel 9 project use vite js. There is a problem: I can't expose host of resources out of docker containers. It's still working in the inside docker containers.
Are there any advice ? Thanks.

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    mem_limit: "512M"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./api
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html/api
      - type: bind
        source: ./docker/nginx/dev/default.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  php:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/dev/Dockerfile
    mem_limit: "512M"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./api
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html/api

  oracle:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
      # - 5500:5500
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: oracle
        target: /opt/oracle/oradata

volumes:
  oracle:
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you tried. For example have you tried (if you are using just docker) to use the `-p` option (described [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/))? Or if you are using docker-compose have you tried using [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)?

Answer (score 7):

I figured out issue. Caused vite does not expose host to network.
My solution is:

1. edit file package.json

> ```
> "scripts": {
>   "dev": "vite --host",
>   "build": "vite build"
> }
> ```

2. expose 5173 port in docker-compose.yml file

> ```
> php:
>     platform: linux/amd64
>     build:
>       context: .
>       dockerfile: ./docker/php/dev/Dockerfile
>     mem_limit: "512M"
>     ports:
>       - 5173:5173
>     volumes:
>       - type: bind
>         source: ./api
>         target: /usr/share/nginx/html/api
> ```

Answer (score -1):

There has been voiced downsides to named volumes [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70802617/4882421).

> Since you can't access the contents of a named volume from outside of Docker, they're harder to back up and manage, and a poor match for tasks like injecting config files and reviewing logs.

Would you try altering all volume types to bind.

[Mount volume from host in Dockerfile long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70798717/mount-volume-from-host-in-dockerfile-long-format)

Comment: thank you @katxeus, but it does not work